# Mono OSX Owin Web API Setup- How to setup MaxMessageSize?

Tags: macos, mono, owin, self-hosting

I have an OWIN Selfhosted WebAPI with a Controller that accepts a large file as input. The code works in PC without any problems or errors.  However in MONO on OSX, the message stays in hung mode in Chrome. When I supply a small size file using Base64 string, the call gets through.  This helped me conclude that my file which is of size 1.5 MB is not an acceptable Base64 message size for POST on MONO with OSX.

However I tried using maxContentSize to a gig on HttpRunTime and Also tried OWIN Middleware implementation with setting MaxRequestSizeInBytes to a Gig.  Both of these did not let me POST the file still to Web API Controller and request stays in pending status.

Please let me know, if you have any other ideas for setting up Max Message Size or know if there is something on MONO preventing file of size 1.5 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for MAC using OwinMiddleware.  Even if I increased the message size, it didn't work, however below solution let me bypass the message size limitation (65K max).

```
 public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
            {
                try
                {
                    IOwinRequest request = context.Request;

                    if (request.Path.HasValue && request.Path.Value.Contains("METHODNAMEFORLARGEFILE"))
                    {
                        //TODO: Remove Workaround for MAC to explicitly download whole stream to avoid issues with message size.  PC works without this workaround.
                        LogHelper.Logger.Info("OWIN METHODNAMEFORLARGEFILE Request");
                        var stream = request.Body;

                        string requestBody = await (new StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEndAsync();

                        var requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
                        context.Request.Body = new MemoryStream(requestData);
                    }

                    await Next.Invoke(context);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    LogHelper.Logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
```